# Retrieving from different tables in PHP Oracle DB

Tags: php, sql, database, oracle

I have a PHP code to retrieve data from multiple tables eg:

```
SELECT RC.customer_id, RC.customer_number, RAA.address_id, RAA.customer_id FROM apps.RA_CUSTOMERS RC, apps.RA_ADDRESSES_ALL RAA WHERE RC.customer_number = 89
```

However, since customer_id is in two separate tables, how do I retrieve it? For everything else, in the while() loop, I can just do

```
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
$row['CUSTOMER_NUMBER']; //this works!
$row['RC.CUSTOMER_ID']; //this does not ...
$row['CUSTOMER_ID']; //this works, but how do I know which table is this from?
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use an `ALIAS` like `RC.customer_id AS cid` and `RAA.customer_id AS raa_cid`.

```
SELECT RC.customer_id AS cid, RC.customer_number, RAA.address_id, RAA.customer_id AS raa_cid FROM apps.RA_CUSTOMERS RC, apps.RA_ADDRESSES_ALL RAA WHERE RC.customer_number = 8
```

Now toy can call it using

```
$row['cid']; //the one from RA_CUSTOMERS
$row['raa_cid']; //the one from RA_ADDRESSES_ALL
```

As you see by placing an alias now you call them and print by using alias given

Answer (score 1):

First of all consider using `JOIN` syntax.

Secondly you can always explicitly give an alias to the column.

```sql
SELECT RC.customer_id rc_customer_id 
       ... 
       RAA.customer_id raa_customer_id
       ...
```

But in that particular case you probably don't need neither second column nor an alias. If you meant to join those two tables they will be the same.

```sql
SELECT RC.customer_id, 
      ,RC.customer_number 
      ,RAA.address_id 
      -- you probably don't need this column ,RAA.customer_id 
  FROM apps.RA_CUSTOMERS RC JOIN apps.RA_ADDRESSES_ALL RAA 
    ON RC.customer_id = RAA.customer_id
 WHERE RC.customer_number = 89
```